# warning in dev console in reactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react JS application I got this warning in console:

```
browser.js?26d3:49 Warning: <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.
```

I do it this way:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, hashHistory, Switch, NavLink, Route} from "react-router-dom";


render() {
    const {t} = this.props;
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppContainer>
                <Router history={createHistory}>
                    <div>
```

If I do the above mentioned change in the warning the application does not run anymore and throws errors

one of the looks like this:

```
AppContainer.dev.js?cd84:95 TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two option here:

A: Use `BrowserRouter` and simply **don't pass history** to it:

```
<Router>
```

Or

```
import {BrowserRouter, hashHistory, Switch, NavLink, Route} from "react-router-dom";
...
<BrowserRouter>
```

B: Use `Router` and pass **instantiated history** object:

```
import {Router, hashHistory, Switch, NavLink, Route} from "react-router-dom";
const history = createHistory();
...
<Router history={history}>
```

Comment: I've chosen B. Now I got this warning `Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack`